# How to set parameters to show data from a period of time in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I created a SQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [stored procedure name]
(
    @Location [varchar](255),
    @start_date datetime,
    @end_date datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT id, location, name, begin_date, age, career, phone_number
    FROM information
    WHERE (begin_date = @start_date OR @start_date IS NULL) 
    AND (begin_date = @end_date OR @end_date IS NULL)
    AND (location = @Location OR @Location = 'All')
END
```

My thought is to set `@start_date` and `@end_date` default to `Null` but it can also show specific data from a period of time if user select to do so, which means:

1. When I run the following code:

```
    EXEC [stored procedure name] @start_date = NULL, @end_date = NULL, @Location = 'New York';
```

It will show all data from New York regardless of time.

2. When I run the following code:

```
    EXEC [stored procedure name] @start_date = '2020-03-01', @end_date = '2020-03-31', @Location = 'New York';
```

It will show data from New York during March 1st, 2020 to March 31st, 2020.
How can I adjust my code to achieve this goal? It seems that my code lacks a connection between `@start_date` and `@end_date`.

Comment: Since you are passing your date variables in `date` format and  your `begin_date` field is `datetime` it may be worth converting to date before doing the match. i.e. `CONVERT(DATE,begin_date)>= @start_date`

Comment: Although for performance reasons its best **not** to convert your columns in a `where` clause. Which is why a range check taking into account time is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close - you just need to make use of greater than equal to (`>=`) and less than (`<`) instead of equals (`=`) for your comparisons.

```
SELECT id, location, name, begin_date, age, career, phone_number
FROM information
WHERE (begin_date >= @start_date or @start_date is null) 
And (begin_date < dateadd(day, 1, @end_date) or @end_date is null)
And (location = @Location or @Location = 'All')
```

Note 1: the `dateadd(day, 1, @end_date)` is to take into account any time part of `begin_date`, so you can set `@end_date` to `31 May 2020` and include any entries that fall on that day.

Note 2: Unless you wish to specify a time component of the incoming parameter I would use a `date` datatype to avoid any unexpected behaviour happening with this compare. In fact `begin_date` should probably also just be a `date` as I don't think you normally track the time that someone starts.

As an aside if you default your parameters e.g.

```
(
    @Location [varchar](255),
    @start_date datetime = null,
    @end_date datetime = null
)
```

You don't have to explicitly pass them in e.g.

```
EXEC [stored procedure name] @Location = 'New York';
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very detailed. But I have a question: is it the same to use `begin_date < dateadd(day, 1, @end_date)` and `begin_date <= @end_date`?

Comment: @VivHuang if there is guaranteed to be no time component (your column and parameter are both datetime) then those 2 expressions are equivalent (and you would benefit from changing the datatype to `date` to avoid this issue). If there is any chance of a time component then they are different and you need the `dateadd` version.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you missing the range check as you matching exact dates

```
    SELECT id, location, name, begin_date, age, career, phone_number
    FROM information
    WHERE (begin_date >= @start_date or @start_date is null) 
    And (begin_date <= @end_date or @end_date is null)
    And (location = @Location or @Location = 'All')
```

Comment: How does this differ from my answer?

Comment: @DaleK there was no answer when I start typing this. And I dont go and read what others have answered. if it helps anyone they will take it. Thats about it!